# Tkinter change number in multiple labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a program that lets a user input a flower type, and it will make a new row with row#, name, and days remaining before it dies. At the moment the UI is a bit messy and code could be improved a lot but that's not the point. I would like to know how I would go about making multiple new labels that I can change the days remaining with the click of a button.

Here is my code so far:

It runs ok but only the lastest made row can be changed, this is because every time one is made, the last one can't be edited anymore, and that's what I want to change.

```
from tkinter import *

#Flower Types

flowers_days = {
    "peony": 1,
    "rose": 2,
    "daffodil": 3,
    "dandelion": 4,
    "lavender": 5
}
day_change = {}

#Variables
day = 1
days_left = 5
row_Num = 0
name = ""

#Commands


def new_flower():
    #make a new line with the new flower
    global row_Num
    global days_left
    global name
    global new_row

    row_Num += 1

    name = str(clicked.get())
    print("Test:" + name)

    days_left = flowers_days[clicked.get()]

    day_change[days_left] = int(row_Num)

    new_row = Label(main_Frame, text=str(row_Num)+"    "+name+"    " + str(days_left))
    new_row.pack()

    return new_row


def next_day():
    global days_left
    global name
    days_left -= 1
    new_row.config(text=str(row_Num)+"    "+name+"    " + str(days_left))


root = Tk()

new_row = Label()

clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set("No option Selected")

#FLOWER TYPE
flower_Type_Frame = LabelFrame(root, text="New Flowers", padx=5, pady=5)
flower_Type_Frame.grid(row=0, rowspan=4, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)
flower_Type_Label = Label(flower_Type_Frame, text="Flower Type:")
flower_Type_Label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

flower_Type_Drop = OptionMenu(flower_Type_Frame, clicked, """
No option Selected
""", "peony", "rose", "daffodil", "dandelion", "lavender")
flower_Type_Drop.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=5)

flower_Type_Submit = Button(flower_Type_Frame, text="Submit", padx=10, pady=10, command=new_flower)
flower_Type_Submit.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2)


#Empty slot
space_Frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Empty", padx=5, pady=5)
space_Frame.grid(row=0, rowspan=4, column=3, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)
space_Fill = Label(space_Frame, text="Space          ").grid(row=0, column=0)


#Day Pass
day_Pass_Frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Day Pass", padx=5, pady=5)
day_Pass_Frame.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=6, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)
day_Pass = Button(day_Pass_Frame, text="Next Day", padx=10, pady=10, command=next_day)
day_Pass.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=3, columnspan=2)


#Row Delete


#Main stuff
main_Frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Flowers In Stock", padx=5, pady=5)
main_Frame.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=7, padx=10, pady=10)
header = Label(main_Frame, text="   Row #   /   Flower Type   /   Days Remaining   ", padx=5, pady=5)
header.pack(padx=5, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Once this is sorted I also plan on making it to have a remove row button, so the row numbers need to be able to be changed too if possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should use a list to store the new row instead of updating the global variable `new_row`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're keeping only one 'days_left' information (in a global variable), but you
need to keep one for each flower. So your main data structure needs to be a
list of flowers, and you should remove the 'global' statements for days_left,
name, new_row, as that information needs to be secific to each flower.

Add this to the global scope (just before the new_flower() definition):

```
# List of [name, days_left, label], one per flower
flowers = []
```

In the new_flower() function, add the newly-created flower to the list with 'append':

```
new_row = Label(main_Frame, text=str(row_Num)+"    "+name+"    " + str(days_left))
new_row.pack()
flowers.append([name, days_left, new_row])
```

The next_day function should look like this:

```
def next_day():
    for i, f in enumerate(flowers):
        # f is a 3-element list [name, days_left, label]
        f[1] -= 1
        name, days_left, label = f
        label.config(text=str(i+1)+"    "+name+"    " + str(days_left))
```

The 'enumerate' call iterates over a list, returning both the current index in
the list (in 'i') and the current list item (in 'f'). The index gives you the
row number.